# Using a nested SELECT to retrieve multiple rows always returns ORA-01427 (Subquery returns more than one row) error or Missing Element Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pretty new to SQL and I know there has been alot of discussion about this particular question but all the examples that i have followed have not yielded the results that I expected.

I am trying to retrieve multiple rows of data that are tied to a single ID in a table. This data typically has two rows, so i was trying to get the query to return the data, no matter how many rows, and then in the rest of my program display the data as needed.

I have been using TOAD in order to verify that my SQL statements actually work, so i wrote them their first and then tried to implement them in the application that i have been working on.

There are three examples that i wrote but none of them work the way i had intended. In the application i am trying to add this query to the existing query that another programmer already wrote.

1) TOAD:

```
SELECT carid
FROM tableA
WHERE carid IN ((SELECT DISTINCT NVL(carid, 'No ID')
FROM tableA ta, tableM tm
WHERE ta.ID = tm.ID AND tm.ID = 7));
```

QUERY in Application:

```
qStr.append("SELECT carid");
qstr.append("FROM "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableA")+" ");
qStr.append("WHERE carid IN ((SELECT DISTINCT NVL(carid, 'No ID') ");
qStr.append("FROM "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableA")+" ta, "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableM")+" tm ");
qStr.append("WHERE ta.ID = tm.ID AND tm.ID = "+idString+") AS carAlias, );
```

The Query above comes back with a MISSING EXPRESSION ERROR, in the application, and i cannot find what i am missing.

Also in the application i am trying to assign an alias to the returned values so that i can manipulate the data later in the program.

2) TOAD:

```
SELECT NVL(carid, 'No ID')
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableM tm ON ta.ID = tm.ID
WHERE tm.ID=7;
```

QUERY in Application:

```
qStr.append("(");
qStr.append("SELECT NVL(carid, 'No ID') ");
qStr.append("FROM "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableA")+" ta ");
qStr.append("INNER JOIN "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableM")+" tm ON ta.ID = tm.ID ");
qStr.append("WHERE tm.ID = "+idString+"");
qStr.append(") AS carAlias ,");
```

The Query above, runs and works but still throws the ORA-01427 error when it encounters SELECTS that return more than one row.

3) TOAD:

```
SELECT NVL(carid, 'No ID');
FROM tableA ta
JOIN tableM tm ON ta.ID = tm.ID
WHERE tm.ID = 7;
```

Query in Application:

```
qStr.append("(");
qStr.append("SELECT NVL(carid, 'No ID') ");
qStr.append("FROM "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableA")+" ta ");
qStr.append("JOIN "+(String)session.getAttribute("tableM")+" tm ON ta.ID = tm.ID ");
qStr.append("WHERE tm.ID = "+idString+"");
qStr.append(") AS carAlias, ");
```

The Query above is another variation on case 2) so it still fails when multiple rows are returned.

I know it is a pretty simple SELECT statement, but i feel that i have explored various solutions but still haven't found a suitable solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Ora" errors and "Toad" usually suggest the Oracle database, so I tagged it appropriately.

Comment: @paqogomez - ever heard of `sub-queries`?

Comment: You say "*none of them work the way i had intended*". Please elaborate.

Comment: Your #2 and #3 are **exactly** the same.

Comment: Based on your code sections, it looks like these are subqueries to a larger query.  If you are using these queries to check for equality (=) then try replacing the (=) with (in).  The 1427 is the result of telling oracle to see if dog=(cat, mouse, horse, dog).  Dog doesn't equal all that, it only equals dog.  dog however is in the recordset of (cat,mouse,horse,dog).

Comment: @PM77-1  I wanted the queries to return the rows that i was trying to retrieve as a single entity, that i could then manipulate later. I went back to the query and ended up using LISTAGG as a way to return all the rows that i wanted as a single row, and then handled the data later on in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, your first version would work if you had a proper correlated subquery.  The problem is that `TableA` is mentioned twice.  You don't need it in the subquery:

```
SELECT carid
FROM tableA ta
WHERE carid IN (SELECT NVL(tm.carid, 'No ID')
                FROM tableM tm
                WHERE ta.ID = tm.ID AND tm.ID = 7
               );
```

The `select distinct` is not needed for an `in` subquery.  The database knows not to worry about duplicate values.

EDIT:

You didn't give the layout of the tables.  So perhaps the above won't work because `tm.carid` doesn't exist.  If so, then try this:

```
SELECT carid
FROM tableA ta
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableM tm
              WHERE ta.ID = tm.ID AND tm.ID = 7
             );
```

Although putting sample code in a question is very useful, it is also helpful to include sample data and desired results.  That can really help clarify a question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I went back to the query after reading your comments and re-evaluated the statement.  I actually ended up using LISTAGG in order to return the rows that i was retrieving as a single row, and then handled the data after.